# Multiple domains for multiple single installs

Tags: directory, domain

I've done my share of searching, but apparently my search-fu is failing me, because I haven't found anything that really seems to fit my circumstance. **Also, I don't want to just try random solutions and end up bricking everything.**

I have a client who has previously managed her site and installations herself and has now hired me on to take things over.

Currently there is **one hosting account** with **two domains**.

**The host is GoDaddy. It's a Deluxe linux account.**

- There is a Wordpress installation in the root directory of the account, currently serving **domain1.com**
- There is a **second Wordpress installation** in a directory (domain1.com/domain2). This install is suppose to be serving **domain2.com**. Which it does, but it's also posing a bunch of problems.

Under the installation for domain2.com ( installed in domain1.com/domain2 ), I **can't change the permalink settings** to anything but default with out breaking the entire site.

- **Changing the permalink settings** results in the warning that Wordpress can't write to .htaccess. **Despite** the .htaccess permissions being set to 644 (I even tried 777).
- So I **manually edited** the .htaccess file to Wordpress's generated content.
- **This results in the site 'breaking'**. The front page shows some default content that I don't recognize and none of the links result in pages being loaded. Just the default 'page not found'.

Under the General settings the install is set to:

```
WordPress Address (URL) : http://www.domain1.com/domain2
Site Address (URL) : http://www.domain2.com
```

**IS it possible to successfully run two separate domains from two separate Wordpress installs, under the same hosting account, with out switching everything over to a network?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serve both sites from the same installation.

In your `wp-config.php` include the settings depending on `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`.

Example for a complete `wp-config.php`:

```
define( 'DB_HOST',     'localhost' );
define( 'DB_CHARSET',  'utf8' );
define( 'DB_COLLATE',  'utf8_general_ci' );

if ( 'example.net' === $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ) // .net domain
    include 'example.net.config.php';
elseif ( 'example.com' === $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ) // .com domain
    include 'example.com.config.php';
else
    die( 'something went wrong' ); // improve this error message

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || define( 'ABSPATH', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' );
```

The `.htaccess` rewrite rules for single site installations are always the same, so don’t worry about conflicts.

If there are some identical settings in `example.net.config.php` and `example.com.config.php` you can move these to the main file, the authentication keys and salts for example or basic DB constants.