# Multiple domains for with a single instal

Tags: multisite, multi-language, domain

I have to create a new project that is multi regional. 
I need to change the website url depending on the user IP address.

On my project, we will have three different domains:

- Our main site: www.mysite.com
- Our uk domain: www.mysite.co.uk
- Our Australian domain: www.mysite.com.au

This project, has to be managed by only one **site installation**

Here is what I was thinking:

1. Modify the htaccess file of the two "extend" domains (co.uk and com.au) to redirect users to my main one: www.mysite.com

   Here is my htaccess redirection on both of my "extend" domains (co.uk and com.au)
   Redirect 301 /  http://www.mysite.com/
2. On my single Wordpress instal where the site will be (.com), I will get users Ip addresses

   To it, I used the geoiploc library (working perfectly)
3. If the user has an Uk or an AU Ip, I will redirect him to the
   according url.

Here is my issue:
I tried to modify the url inside the function.php according to the IP detection like this.

update_option('siteurl','http://www.mysite.co.uk');
 update_option('home','http://www.mysite.co.uk');

Redirections are working (can review links modification on the page).
However, since I have done my "extend" domains redirections, I will always display the .com website.

So how can I avoid this problem?

Note: I found that I can use the [multiple domains with analytics plug-in](http://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-domains-with-analytics/) that will be very helpful. However, this plug-in requires "DNS settings".

**Does my "extend" domains htaccess modification is enough?**

Here is my plug-in set-up on my .com website:

- Domain 1: www.mysite.co.uk
- Wordpress address (URL): www.mysite.com
- Blog address (URL): www.mysite.com
- Domain 2: www.mysite.com.au
- Wordpress address (URL): www.mysite.com.au
- Blog address (URL): www.mysite.com.au

Note: Latter I will add a drop down list to allow users domains swapping (.com, .co.uk, .con.au)

Any help will be appreciated, cheers!

Comment: Have you seen http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96684/two-or-more-parallel-sub-tlds-that-are-retained-when-surfing-the-site-dyna and http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/90612/multiple-domains-for-multiple-single-installs/90621#90621?

Comment: Yes, I did. But, I need to implement a drop down to let the user to select a domain. So, modifying the config file doesn't sound good. Let me try